# Remove the only index on an array php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to print an array on php when I use

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

It shows me this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "x": "145",
        "y": "20"
    },
    "2": {
        "x": "145",
        "y": "40"
    }
}
```

but I want this:

```
{
    {
         "x":"145",
         "y":"20"
    },
    {
        "x":"145",
        "y":"40"
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: So how would you get a specific index value then?

Comment: the json you want is not quite valid, you have two objects nested in another object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `array_values` like as

```
echo json_encode(array_values($array));
```

Comment: $your_json it's an array not a string

Comment: I'm not sir. Well glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to achieve this you need to strutire your array like this;

```
$arr = array(array("x"=>145, "y"=>20),array("x"=>145, "y"=>40));
```

or

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array("x"=>145, "y"=>20);
$arr[] = array("x"=>145, "y"=>20);
```

This will then give you the following for json_encode

```
[{"x":145,"y":20},{"x":145,"y":20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{
    $newArray[] = $val;
}

print_r(json_encode($newArray));

**Result**: [{"x":"145","y":"20"},{"x":"145","y":"40"}]
```